# How to convert SQL time to total minutes?

Tags: java, sql, date, time

I am using `java.sql.Time` class for representing time. I need to convert the time to total minutes in java.

`01:10:00` this is my time duration. I need to convert it into 70 minutes.

Please suggest me some good links.

Comment: Do you have a milliseconds time value?

Comment: 01:10:00 this is my time duration.I need to convert it into minutes(70).

Comment: `java.sql.time` extends `java.util.Date` which represents a point in time, not a period of time, which is what you're dealing with here.

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem: It's tested here

```
private static int toMins(String s) {
    String[] hourMin = s.split(":");
    int hour = Integer.parseInt(hourMin[0]);
    int mins = Integer.parseInt(hourMin[1]);
    int hoursInMins = hour * 60;
    return hoursInMins + mins;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
private  int toMins(String s) {
        String[] hourMin = s.split(":");
        int hour = Integer.parseInt(hourMin[0]);
        int mins = Integer.parseInt(hourMin[1]);
        int hoursInMins = hour * 60;
        return hoursInMins + mins;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first use the `toString()` method to get a `String` from you `java.sql.Time` object. Then you have to parse this string, calculating the proper minutes value. Here is an example:

```
java.sql.Time date = new java.sql.Time(1,10,0);

String stringDate = date.toString();
String[] hAndm = stringDate.split(":");

int minutes = Integer.parseInt(hAndm[0])*60 + Integer.parseInt(hAndm[1]);
System.out.println(minutes);
```

Note that the constructor `Time(int hour, int minute, int second)` is deprecated. You should use instead `Time(long time)` which constructs a Time object using a milliseconds time value.